# INSERT ROW doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

Config.php

```
  $host = 'REMOVED';
  $dbname = 'REMOVED';
  $username = 'REMOVED';
  $password = 'REMOVED';

  try {
  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$dbname, $username, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage());
  }
```

The config connects to the server just fine, then I try to insert a row in index.php to the table, and then...

Index.php

```
require 'config.php';

$text1 = 'teeext';

$text2 = 'teeeext';

$text3 = 'teeeeext';

$db->exec('INSERT INTO users (`row1`, `row3`, `row2`) VALUES ('.$text1.', '.$text2.', '.$text3);
```

When I run this page, I just get blank, database does not show any rows inserted, even if I run the page 100 times.

Comment: Because running the page 100 times might cause it to work, when it didn't the first time?

Comment: [PHP's white screen of death](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death).

Comment: Try using 
`$db->exec("INSERT INTO users (\`row1\`, \`row3\`, \`row2\`) VALUES ('$text1', '$text2', '$text3')");`

Comment: @mega6382 same shit.

Comment: See if you can view the error log (for apache it's usually in /var/log/httpd or /var/log/apache2 depending on your distribution).  This should tell you the exact problem. If you don't have access you may be able to use a .htaccess file to point it to a file you can view.

Comment: As @mega6382 says, you have a sintax error. It won't work even if you run it 1000000000 times

Comment: I have updated my comment try that. And also, if any of the values for those variables will be coming from external input, then your code is at risk of sql injection.

Answer (score -1):

There is an syntax error, at the end of the query you didnt close for `'.$text3.'`

```
$db->exec('INSERT INTO users (`row1`, `row3`, `row2`) VALUES ('.$text1.', '.$text2.', '.$text3.')');
```

Comment: Shouldn't the string values be in quotes, also?  Also, while it's good to try to help how can you be sure this is the right data structure?  Are you sure? How do you know.

Comment: As the query assigned as string  " ' " at the begining of the $text3 and didnt close the query correctly.

Comment: this syntax is incorrect  and don't know why it was upvoted.

Comment: No one has upvoted, as it was downvoted for duplicate questions.

Comment: @San - it has been both upvoted _and_ downvoted.

Comment: click in the middle of the arrows, you'll see for yourself.

Comment: @cale_b oh some one has wrongly upvoted.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't think San can see that.  I don't recall the rep required, but fairly confident it's more than 30...  (Just checked - it's 1k)